# Jsoup Timeout not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jsoup

I've written a small piece of code which should download the text of a given website with Jsoup (1.6.2).

```
public String readPage(String url) {

    try {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String text = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get().html();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        return text;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        // we need to do this because the log file is flooded with useless error messages 
        if ( e.getMessage().contains("Unhandled content type") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("Premature EOF") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("Read timed out") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("403 error loading URL") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("404 error loading URL") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("405 error loading URL") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("500 error loading URL") ||
             e.getMessage().contains("503 error loading URL") ) {

            logger.debug(String.format("Error crawling website: %s", url));
        }
        else logger.error(String.format("Error crawling website: %s", url), e);
    }

    return "";
}
```

I'm starting this method in inside of a list of threads, each thread responsible for downloading a single website. In my point of view (and this is obviously wrong), every system.out should show a number below 10000 because Jsoup should throw a Exception. But this is not the case there are timespans higher than 100k in the stdout.

How is this possible and what am I doing wrong?

Cheers
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't surprise me. There are a lot of things happening between when you get the start time and the finish time. The connection could have been made before the deadline and your end time could easily be beyond the deadline depending on how fast the downloads are taking (especially since you're doing several at once).

You commented:

> I'm sorry but could you please explain this in more detail?

You have this line:

```
String text = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get().html();
```

being called by several threads at once. Imagine a scenario where all of them connect quickly, but it will take time for all of them to download the information and process it, especially with many threads all competing for the same resource.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Supose that `thread 1` executes `long start = System.currentTimeMillis()` and system scheduler stops this first thread and starts thread 2nd. 2nd thread invokes `long start = System.currentTimeMillis()` and stops for 3rd thread to invoke its code.

This is indeterminate - the system scheduler can assign running the n'th thread after all threads compleated - the System.out.println can be as long as all threads duration.

The timeout works - but threading is here the issue.